# Can anyone explain the distinction between sects/cults In Korean Martial Arts (Murim) Manhwa?

Tags: tropes, the-breaker

A common trope seen in many Korean martial arts stories is the existence of Orthodox/Unorthodox sects; or Righteous/Justice, Demonic and Evil Sects. One thing that tripped me is how 'demonic' sects are different from 'evil' sects, when same have the similar sounding negative connotations.

What exactly are the difference between these terms in context of Korean culture/history?
Is it purely ideological/political distinction?

Answer (score 3):

Justice: the most righteous faction

Orthodox: second to the righteous faction

Righteous: consist of all factions that lean to the right

Unorthodox: can lean both left and right and consider a third faction, distinguish from both righteous and evil sects

Evil sects: consist of all faction that lean to the left

Demon sects: the most evil faction

For politic, the justice faction consider strength through bond and alliance while the evil sect consider strength have to be earn (or even killing people to dominate it).

Therefore, in evil sect, the righteous faction is considered as hypocrite. And as for the righteous faction, the evil sect is considered as selfish and lust for power.

In Korean history, there were Chinese officers who ran off Qin Shi Huang when they failed to get the youth pills for the king back then. Since then Korean culture has been influenced by Chinese culture.

Whenever a manhwa has Mount Hua faction, the world setting considered as the Chinese Murim world since there is Mount Hua in real world, located at near the city of Huayin in Shaanxi Province.

Comment: Thanks, I too had noticed how Martial arts Manhwa with the Mount Hua faction were usually based in china. If I may ask, what exactly is the Mount Hua faction.